# Alfresco 5.1 сортировка документов

Tags: alfresco

Доброго времени суток всем. Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу понять почему alfresco сортирует (группирует) документы криво. То есть в примере, создаю документы под названием "1, 2 , 3 и тд до 9" сортирует нормально по возрастанию, но как только добавляю документ под названием 10, он пихает его сразу после "1" , то есть получается 1, 10, 2, 3 и тд.
Подскажите пожалуйста, куда смотреть и где исправить это

Answer (score 1):

Тип поля "*Наименование документа*" (cm:name) – текст, следовательно, элементы сортируются как текст, а не как числа